# How to query database for large datasets, where only some aggregated infos are required

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, web-applications, nosql

I am building an **interactive real-time Twitter analytics application where users can search for (combinations of) keywords and/or usergroups out of collected Tweets** and receive insights about this selection in a dashboard-like view.
The dashboard consists out of several widgets all needing only some fields of the Twitter JSON object - but often aggregated for the whole user-defined selection of Tweets or users (e.g. show a chart with the number of tweets per day for the usergroup "republicans" and the keyword "taxes" -> need to scan all `tweet.created_at` fields and sum them up for each day)

The collected Tweets (around 1 million, but could be more) are stored in a document-oriented database. Furthemore, I am using a Node/Express server with socketio for server-client messaging and React as the view engine.

How do I **query my database most efficiently** to get the initial view for my dashboard?

Some apporaches:

1) Do one query and fetch ALL matching Tweet and User objects and send unprocessed to client. Do the filtering and stuff with React.

2) Do one query and fetch ALL matching Tweet and User objects, process it on the server, and send only the data to the client which is needed to render the initial view (e.g. the first 20 most recent Tweets, data for the tweet count statistics etc.)

3) Query the db only for the user ids and tweet ids matching the search and let each widget fetch data from the db based on those ids, which are kept on the server (e.g. in the socket object)

---

Option 1: NOPE. Browser gets laggy after only 5000 tweets in the state. Also, I do not need to display all the information, only little of it, so why push it all to the client.

Option 2: Mh sounds ok but then my server has to handle a lot of data and does not scale with the number of users of the app?

Option 3: Only data needed for rendering is pulled from db, but around 5 - 10 queries are fired. Maybe slow over the network? But my widgets are quite autonomous. For example for a small Tweet stream, I can change the ordering from 'most recent' to 'most liked' without pulling ALL the tweet objects first from the db, but get only the 20 tweets with the most likes based on the ids I kept in the socket object.

Currently I am doing option 3 but I am worried this is not a solution which is very scalable and efficient.

Comment: Why don't you do this completely client-side? Can't you specify all that when making calls to the Twitter API directly?

Comment: I need to store collected tweets in in the db to not rely on api tokens and to be able to search tweets for some time in the past. It just gives me more flexibility in general.